# How do I set the current time in Embarcadero's DateTimePicker?

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo, tdatetimepicker

I am using Embarcadero's C++Builder 10.2 and a `TDateTimePicker` control.  I have been trying to find a way to set the picker's date to today's date every time I create this Form. So far, I have been unsuccessful. If I try the example given using `DateTime.Now`, the error message reads `"undefined symbol DateTime"`. My code is in the `TForm3::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)` event, as I only need this info when this form is created.

When I type in `DateTimePicker1->` there is a dropdown box with all of the functions, operators, etc., that are available but none of them seem to be able to get todays date and put it into the format for the control.

It would be appreciated if anyone can help me with figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

In the Form's constructor (DO NOT use the `TForm::OnCreate` event in C++!), you can assign the return value of the [`System::Sysutils::Date()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Date) function, or the [`System::TDateTime::CurrentDate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime.CurrentDate) class method, to the [`TDateTimePicker::Date`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.Date) property:

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    DateTimePicker1->Date = System::Sysutils::Date();
    // or:
    // DateTimePicker1->Date = System::TDateTime::CurrentDate();
}
```

This is clearly demonstrated in Embarcadero's [DateUtils (C++)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/DateUtils_(C%2B%2B)) example, which is linked to in the [`TDateTimePicker`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker) documentation.

I don't know what example you are referring to, but there is no `DateTime` type in C++Builder (or Delphi), that is why you are getting a compiler error.  The correct type name is `TDateTime` instead, but [`Now()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Now) is not a method of the `TDateTime` class, it is a standalone function in the `System::Sysutils` namespace instead:

```
DateTimePicker1->DateTime = System::Sysutils::Now();
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know why I should not use the OnCreate event.

Comment: @user427921 `OnCreate`/`OnDestroy`  are Delphi idioms that can introduce illegal behavior in C++. Use the constructor/destructor instead